# Powershell [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry] does not contain a method named 'ExtractToFile'

Tags: .net, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script where I'd like to extract specific entries. I can't seem to figure out how to get past the error where it can't find the extension methods on the .NET ZipArchiveEntry object.

My script below will run and will "write out" the files from the zip but when it gets to the **$entry.ExtractToFile($dst)** line, it produces the following error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry] does not contain a method named 'ExtractToFile'.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression -ErrorAction Stop
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem -ErrorAction Stop

$filesToExtract = @(
    "appsettings.json";
    "Content\cms\index.xml";
)
$archive = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\archive.zip"
$dstRoot = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test"
$zip = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($archive)
foreach($entry in $zip.Entries){
    if ($filesToExtract -contains $entry.FullName){
        $dst = [io.path]::combine($dstRoot, $entry.FullName)
        %{ "Extract ==> " + $dst }        

        $entry.ExtractToFile($dst)

    }
}
$zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: According to the documentation, [it doesn't](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry(v=vs.110).aspx).  It's an extension, but I'm not sure how that works in PowerShell with `Add-Type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]. It will fail if the extract file already exists.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem -ErrorAction Stop

$filesToExtract = @(
    "t.txt";
)
$archive = "$PSScriptRoot\t.zip"
$dstRoot = "$PSScriptRoot"
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($archive)

foreach($entry in $zip.Entries){
    if ($filesToExtract -contains $entry.FullName){
        $dst = [io.path]::combine($dstRoot, $entry.FullName)

        if (Test-Path -Path $dst) { Remove-Item -Path $dst }

        Write-Verbose $("Extract ==> {0}" -f @($dst))
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($entry, $dst)
    }
}
$zip.Dispose()
```